# How to solve: ReferenceError: app is not defined

Tags: node.js, express

I'm getting an error saying ReferenceError: app is not defined.

my code is below:

```
import express from "express";
import chatbotControllers from "../controllers/chatbotControllers";

let app = express();

let initWebRouters = (app) => {
    router.get("/", chatbotControllers.test);
    router.get("/webhook", chatbotControllers.getWebhook);
    router.post("/webhook", chatbotControllers.postWebhook);
};
    app.use("/", Router);

export default initWebRouters;
```

Comment: This code should be creating an error `router` is not defined since there is no `router` variable defined anywhere in this code, but `app` is perfectly available for your `app.use()` statement.  You need to show code that matches the actual error and show enough code that we can reproduce the error.  This code also refers to `Router` which is also not shown.  As it stands now, this question cannot be answered without more details and more code - enough to demonstrate the problem and make it reproducible.

Answer (score 1):

You get an error because you didn't define an app.

```
const app = express()
```

This way you can fix the error.

Answer (score 1):

You are using the `app` variable outside its scope. I think this is what you want

```js
import express from "express";
import chatbotControllers from "../controllers/chatbotControllers";

let router = express();

let initWebRouters = (app) => {
    router.get("/", chatbotControllers.test);
    router.get("/webhook", chatbotControllers.getWebhook);
    router.post("/webhook", chatbotControllers.postWebhook);

    app.use("/", router);
};

export default initWebRouters;
```

And you should not declare `router = express()`. It is more familiar if you use

```js
const app = express();
const router = express.Router();
```

Comment: No I tried as you said but still i'm getting the same error.

Comment: It looks weird. Could you update the code to the question?

Comment: i attached the screenshot

Comment: You still use `app` outside the `initWebRouters` function, and you did not declare the variable `Router`.

Comment: Here is the docs, I think you can find the solution [here](https://expressjs.com/en/guide/routing.html)